# PHP SQLSRV Dropdown list error

Tags: php, dropdown, sqlsrv

> I am trying to populate dropdown list from SQL Query through sqlsrv
>   but it is not working. What am i doing wrong?

```
<?php

$serverName1 = "kk12334";
$connectionInfo1 = array( "Database"=>"Fruits");
$conn1 = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName1, $connectionInfo1);
$sql1="SELECT [Name] as CName,[BName] as BName from Fruits";
$stmt1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn1, $sql1 );


while ($data=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))

{


  echo "<option value=";
    echo $data['CName'].", ".$data['BName'].;
    echo "<br />";
        echo $data['CName'].", ".$data['BName'];
    echo "</option>";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot place a `<BR>` inside an `<option`> tag.

Try something like:

```
while ($data=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{ $opt="$data[CName], $data[BName]";
   echo "<option value='$opt'>$opt</option>\n";
}
```

And since you want a blank between your two variable values you need to enclose everything in `'` to make sure both parts are assigned to `value=`.